# Why is Python eval returning same object for Keras regularizer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, eval

I am trying to convert strings (which I read from a JSON) to arguments that can be used by Keras layers. However when I find that all the regularizer objects created by the eval function are the same.

```
a = eval('l1(0.1)')
b = eval('l2(0.1)')
c = eval('l1_l2(0.1)')
print(a,b,c)
```

gives:

```
<tensorflow.python.keras.regularizers.L1L2 object at 0x0000013F003C2F60>
<tensorflow.python.keras.regularizers.L1L2 object at 0x0000013F003C2D68> 
<tensorflow.python.keras.regularizers.L1L2 object at 0x0000013F0032F160>
```

Shouldn't eval('l1(0.1)') give

```
<function tensorflow.python.keras.regularizers.l1(l=0.01)>
```

Any thoughts on why this is happening would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`L1L2` stores both `l1` and `l2`; on the regularizer, run, for example:

```py
print(model.layers[1].kernel_regularizer.__dict__)
# {'l1': array(0., dtype=float32), 'l2': array(1., dtype=float32)}
```

To access one or the other:

```py
print(model.layers[1].kernel_regularizer.l1) # 0.0
print(model.layers[1].kernel_regularizer.l2) # 1.0
```

In your code, `a` sets `l1`, `b` sets `l2`, and `c` sets both.

---

Full sample script:

```py
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.regularizers import l2
from keras.models import Model

ipt   = Input(shape=(100,4))
x     = Dense(10, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l2(1))(ipt)
out   = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model = Model(ipt, out)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')


print(model.layers[1].kernel_regularizer.__dict__)
print(model.layers[1].kernel_regularizer.l1)
print(model.layers[1].kernel_regularizer.l2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I think I get it now.